# Need an app that tells about file & folder sizes

Tags: macos, disk-space

I need an app that tells about file & folder sizes, like what is the biggest file and/or folder on my hard disk, sort this detail from biggest file and/or folder to the smallest & vice versa, also able to tell me about this detail based on the folder that I have chosen.

Comment: I've had good luck with the free jDiskReport

Answer (score 3):

you can easily do this at the command line by executing the following at the root (/),

```
du -sk * | sort -nr
```

For directories only you can execute:

```
du -sk */
```

Comment: how do I do this for folder only or files only ?

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/).

> Disk Inventory X is a disk usage
>   utility for Mac OS X 10.3 (and later).
>   It shows the sizes of files and
>   folders in a special graphical way
>   called "treemaps". If you've ever
>   wondered where all your disk space has
>   gone, Disk Inventory X will help you
>   to answer this question.

Comment: +1, great suggestion! I use the equivalent software on Windows for exactly this purpose. I updated your link to go to the manufacturer's website directly, rather than to the 3rd party review site, as that'll be more helpful to people viewing your answer :)

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [DaisyDisk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com/). Files and folders are visualized by a ring chart, makes it easy to identify which file/folder takes the most space in the hard disk.

The trial version has no limit on time, just a nagging screen when you launch the app.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

There is also OmniDiskSweeper.

Answer (score 0):

There are two GUI applications for Mac that help visually identify what's taking up disk space: [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) and [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/). If you've ever used [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) or [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.sourceforge.net/) then you should be comfortable with it, but even if not it's fairly self-explanatory when you run it.

[image]

You can also [search by file size in Finder](http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/17/find-large-files-in-mac-os-x-search/).

[image: search by file size in Finder]

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is [Space Radar](https://github.com/zz85/space-radar) (Electron-based, MIT license).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue is just that the `~/Library/Caches` has become huge.

The command

```
du -sh ~/Library/Caches/* | sort -h
```

will give you the usage of each subfolder in Caches folder.