# Analyze Disk Usage?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need an app that tells about file & folder sizes](https://superuser.com/questions/181627/need-an-app-that-tells-about-file-folder-sizes)

Suggestions for a tool that can analyze my Disk Usage and sort them in order of usage? I am running Mac OS X 10.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) or [DaisyDisk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Program is called [DISK INVENTORY X](http://www.derlien.com/)