# how to find biggest files on disk on Mac

Tags: mac, file-management, osx-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need an app that tells about file & folder sizes](https://superuser.com/questions/181627/need-an-app-that-tells-about-file-folder-sizes)

How can I find the largest files on my hard drive? I am using Mac OS X 10.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [GrandPerspectiv](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I download and seem it does not work on my Macbook. :-(

Comment: Any easy to use commands?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but i believe you might be able to use the unix _find_ command. To find files larger than 20000k, try this: `find / -type f -size +20000k`

Answer (score 3):

- command line:

  du -ms $HOME/* | sort -n

and extend to where it looks promising

- nice graphics:

Disk Inventory X : http://www.derlien.com/

Comment: +1 just for DI:X.  Remains one of the staples of my OS X toolbox.