# SOS Online Backup

Tags: macos, mac, backup

I signed up for SOS Online Backup and I ran the backup only to find that it eventually just filled my hard drive to capacity. From what I've read this is done by the way it caches the files it uploads to its server.

I can't seem to find the cache anywhere and their documentation is spotty to non-existent. Where would these files typically be stored in the Mac OS (specifically 10.7)?

I've looked in `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications/OnlineBackup.app/` but there wasn't anything there of relevance. I've also searched my drive for files of size larger than `500 MB` to no success. I realize this is very specific question, but tech support has not responded to me and I'm just wondering if there's anything I can try in the meantime.

Comment: You could use the general approach: http://superuser.com/questions/181627/need-an-app-that-tells-about-file-folder-sizes

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in /Users/~yourusername~/Library/Application Support/OnlineBackup/

You should see your username/email - under that folder is the cache, and yes it's freakin' huge .. I'm looking for way to reduce it otherwise this service will be useless for me.

Hope that help!